# What is the maximum number in the mantissa part of a Java float?

Tags: java

In Java what is the maximum number in the mantissa part that can be stored?

In this link below 
http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html

```
                         Sign       Exponent    Fraction    Bias
Single Precision       1 [31]       8 [30-23]   23 [22-00]  127
```

Does it mean that we can have only 0 to 2^8 combinations stored?

Comment: PLEASE DON'T SHOUT (Edit: I've updated the title to stop the shouting.)

Comment: I don't suggest you use float. double is almost as fast and doesn't have anywhere near the same limitation/round error.

Answer (score 4):

Everything you want to know is on the wikipedia page for IEEE-754: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008.

Answer (score 2):

The mantissa is 23 bits in a `float`, but the stored value is normalized, meaning that there's an implied leading 1 followed by a decimal point.  This takes it to 24 effective bits.

Comment: ...except for denormalized numbers.

Comment: can u explain what is normalized ??                                                        if u say 24 bits then we can represent  2 ^ 24 numbers in the mantissa  part??

Comment: @user733434: "...meaning that there's an implied leading 1 followed by a decimal point."  As @finnw said, there are numbers that are not normalized, if the exponent is all 0 but the fraction is not.  http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html

Answer (score 0):

[What every computer scientist should know about floating point](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).