# Why in one case multiplying big numbers gives a wrong result?

Tags: java, int, multiplication, primitive

This might seem simple but I don't have any answer.
When I write:

```
 System.out.println (100 * 1000 * 10000 * 100000);
 System.out.println (100 * 1000 * 10000 * 100000.0);
```

it returns these values:

```
276447232
1.0E14
```

I understand that this has something to do with maximum values of some data types. But I would just like a clear answer as to why it returns these exact values for both equations. If someone can explain this to me I will be very appreciative.

The first return doesn't match the maximum value for int datatype, that's why I'm confused. And the second return I'm assuming is a double or float value, but I'm not sure.

Comment: "The first return doesn't match the maximum value for int datatype, thats why I'm confused" - well it's already overflowed. It doesn't reach the maximum and stay there.

Comment: `100000000000000 % (2^32)` is 276447232...

Comment: (And yes, the second value is a double value - it's not clear where you're confused there.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the maximum number in the mantissa part of a Java float?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849741/what-is-the-maximum-number-in-the-mantissa-part-of-a-java-float)

Comment: @JonSkeet ok thanks. Just to be clear, the second returned value is supposed to be like that and is not the wrong value right?

Comment: Yeah it's obviously integer overflow, I'm sure that has been answered here already.

Comment: This question seems like it might answer the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo

Comment: Yes, that's 1x10^14.

Comment: @mackanmorre `int * double` will always give you `double`.  And `1000000000 * 100000.0` is certainly `100000000000000.0`.  Don't be thrown by the scientific notation with which that last number is shown.

Comment: Ok thanks all of you! The question has been answered :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the expression

```
System.out.println (100 * 1000 * 10000 * 100000);
```

The parameter is an `int` and the result exceeds the maximum value admissible for an `int` which is `2147483647`. This is what we call an overflow. According to the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.1)

> If an integer multiplication overflows, then the result is the low-order bits of the mathematical product as represented in some sufficiently large two's-complement format.

Taking the N low-order bits of a number is equivalent to computing the remainder of the division of this number by 2^N. In our case, N=32 because `int` are stored on 32 bits. This why Jon Skeet answered by saying

> `100000000000000 % (2^32)` is 276447232.

In the expression

```
System.out.println (100 * 1000 * 10000 * 100000.0);
```

The product of the three first factor `100 * 1000 * 10000` gives `1_000_000_000` which is less than the maximum `int` value. The last multiplication leads to a [Binary Numeric Promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) which means, in this case, that `1_000_000_000` is converted (promoted) to `double` and then multiplied by `100000.0`.