# Loss of accuracy with floats

Tags: java, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I am trying to compute a summation of float numbers. All small numbers output properly, when I use very large numbers as inputs, the output is always off by a few integers. For example, **H** = 5764801 **W** = 1679616, on paper, works out as 335923 **30275911**. In my program though, 335923 **30275908** is printed instead. Here is the code:

```
public void printOutput(int H, int W) // The inputs
{
    if(H == 1 && W == 1)
    {
        System.out.println(0 + " " + 1);
        return;
    }

    List<Integer> pfw = primeFactors(W);

    int y = 1;

    while(H != (int) (Math.pow(Math.pow(W,  1f/y) + 1f, y))) y++; 

    final float N = findWholeNumber(pfw);

    float height = 0;
    for(int x = 1; x <= y + 1; x++)
    {
        height += (float) (W * Math.pow((N + 1f) / N, x-1f) + 1e-8); //Here is the summation
    }
    float cats = 1;
    for(int x = 2; x <= y + 1; x++)
        cats += (float) (Math.pow(N, x-1));

    int notWorking = (int) (cats - W);
    System.out.println(notWorking + " " + (int)height); //Outputs printing
}

private int findWholeNumber(List<Integer> factors)
{
    List<Integer> common = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i < factors.size(); i++)
    {
        if(common.contains(factors.get(i))) continue;
        common.add(factors.get(i));
    }
    int num = common.get(0);
    for(int i = 1; i < common.size(); i++)
        num *= common.get(i);
    return num;
}

private List<Integer> primeFactors(int num)
{
    List<Integer> pf = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    if(num == 1)
    {
        pf.add(1);
        return pf;
    }

    for(int j = 2; j <= num; j++)
        while(num % j == 0) // is prime
        {
            pf.add(j);
            num /= j;
        }

    return pf;
}
```

}

Comment: any reason not to use `double`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating point numbers have a limited precision as mantissa has a limited width.

You could try `double` for your case which precision is more (as its mantissa is wider), but it is also limited.

More information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#IEEE_754-2008 and [What is the maximum number in the mantissa part of a Java float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849741/what-is-the-maximum-number-in-the-mantissa-part-of-a-java-float)

If you need to have an unlimited precision, try `BigDecimal`. The count of significant digits there is only limited by the amount of your memory.

If you only need integer values, `BigInteger` is an option.

Answer (score 1):

Study *What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*, David Goldberg, 1991.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html